# Have Accepts on answers toggle favorite notification in user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accepted-answer, bookmarks, favorites-notifications

It would be nice to have it so that after you add a question to your favorites, that it will be noted as 'changed' in your favorites list **whenever it is accepted**, i.e. treat accepting the same as an edit in regard to notifying favorited users of changes.

This will float the question to the top of your favorites queue, and highlight it, so you can then go and review the question and answers (and comments in the case of bad accepts).

Comment: I would actually prefer if it came in the notification tab(in the top left)

Comment: I can't imagine having all the favorite notifications showing up in the inbox.  Most of the time the favorite changes are pretty miniscule, and I don't chase every one to see what happened.

Comment: Not every comment, but when an answer is accepted, I would prefer to have a notification to having an updated list of favorites(which I rarely look at)